# Find and remove class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following structure:

```
<li id="0" class="instruction">
        <div class="row1">
            title
        </div>
        <div class="row2 details hidden">
            details
        </div>
    </li>
```

css for hidden is:  `display: none`

I'd like when user clicked the instruction, then show the details div.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".instruction").click(function(e){

            $(e).find('.details').removeClass("hidden");


        });
    });
```

Tried to implement something like above, but doesn't work. any idea?

Comment: instead of `e` , use `this`, like this `$(this).find('.details').removeClass("hidden");`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have written '.instructionRow' but as per the html it should be '.instruction'. And use $(this) to refer to the element that is clicked. And usage of 'on' (https://api.jquery.com/on/) is better...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".instruction").on('click', function(e){
        $(this).find('.details').removeClass("hidden");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Off-answer, but ref for Googlers - **vanilla** Javascript option for finding a class and removing a class

```
// Finding all elements of a class (creates an array of results)
let x = document.getElementsByClassName("today");

// If it exists, remove it.
if(x.length > 0) { x[0].classList.remove("today"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".instructionRow").click(function(){

        $(this).find('.details').removeClass("hidden");


    });
});
```

Comment: You should really explain what this does. Give a man a fish — feed him for a day.  Teach a man to fish — feed him for life.

Comment: he already knows how to fish, i am simply showing him a better bait to use